# Fields should be displayed only in detail view not in the edit mode

Tags: fields

I'm creating a custom Object which is exact replica of Case Object. I have few fields like Contact Phone and Contact Email which is displayed only in the detail view but not in the Edit mode. Please suggest me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

The only fields that appear only on detail pages, and not edit pages, are formula fields. For normal fields, you may choose to make the fields read-only, in which case they will appear, but not be editable by the user.

One possible solution is to have two fields per entry: a formula field and the actual underlying data value. You can have two different layouts assigned by profile or record type. When the user views the object, they will see the formula fields on the screen, but they won't appear in edit pages. Users with the actual field, and not the formula field, on the page will be able to edit the field normally.

Comment: @Brian - After Summer 16 formula fields will also show in new and edit screen. Is there any way to hide from the new screen?

Comment: @SarojBera Nope. They would see the labels but not be able to edit the values. There's no way to hide them just during editing anymore.